# sas dynamic call symput with unknown number of fields in the dataset

Tags: sas

I have following dataset

```
data parm2;
    input a b c d e;
    datalines;
1 2 3 4 A
;
run;
```

**Problem1: I would like have a set of macro variables. Assume i do not know the number of fields and its corresponding name of the field.**

**Problem2: fields are not same datatype.**

desired operation is like following:

```
data _null_;
    set parm2;
call symput('a',a);
call symput('b',b);
call symput('c',c);
call symput('d',d);
call symput('e',e);
run;

%put &a;
```

Comment: Look into call vnext. When I have time later I'll post a solution if someone else hasn't already.

Comment: Hi @Reeza, do i need to use do loop? and fields have different datatype

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If this is the structure of your data, I would transpose:

```
proc transpose data=parm2 out=parmt;
  var _all_;
run;
```

Then reference the two columns to create all the macro variables and their corresponding values:

```
data _null_;
  set parmt;
  call symput(_name_,col1);
run;
```

Comment: What happens if you have character and numeric variables?

Comment: @Reeza Now it'll do both.

Answer (score 2):

after some research i found the following solution. Although not a perfect one but worth to share. Looking forward @Reeze answer

```
data _null_;
    set parm2;
    array t(*) _numeric_;   /*this deal with different data type*/
    do i = 1 to dim(t);
        call symput(vname(t[i]), t[i]);
    end;
    array t2(*) _character_;
    do i = 1 to dim(t2);
        call symput(vname(t2[i]), t2[i]);
    end;
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a Call VNEXT solution with VVALUEX, assuming you don't have a variable that has the same name as an automatic variable it seems to work. Derived solution from SAS Note: http://support.sas.com/kb/24/798.html

```
data parm2;
    input a b c d e $;
    datalines;
1 2 3 4 A
;
run;


data _null_;
  set parm2;
  length name $32;

 *temporarily set name to not missing to start loop;
  name='blank';
  do while(name ne " ");
    call vnext(name);

    /* Omit automatic variables, and variables created in this step only */
    if trim(name) not in('list','name','flag','i',' ','_ERROR_','_N_') then 
      call symput(name, vvaluex(name));

  end;
run;

%put &a;
%put &b;
%put &c;
%put &d;
%put &e;
```

Comment: Looks good, but the way you wrote it, the loop never starts because `name` is initialized to missing. Give it a different starting value and it should work.

Comment: The comment let you know that ;)

Comment: Ha, I totally missed that.

Comment: It was in the code at some point, must have pasted an incorrect version somehow.

Answer (score 0):

[ Edited - some codes or lines of code are marked with * as the OP does not require it ]

Use `proc sql` dictionary to get the variable name contained in your datase with the use of `Memname` and `libname` specification.

Use `data step` to obtained variables into marco variable. The name of variables are stored under the column name called `name`, and that's why we have to put it as `call symputx( 'variable ' !! left(_n_), **name** );`. The function of macro variable `Total` is to tell the number of variables existed in your data set.

Now you would have variable1= a , variable2= b....

```
%macro definevar ( library, dataset);
proc sql;
create table Attribute as
select * from dictionary.columns;
where memname = upcase( &dataset ) and libname = upcase(&library);
quit;

data letmacro;
set Attribute end=end;
call symputx( 'variable ' !! left(_n_), name );
* if end then call symputx ( Total, _n_);
run;



/*
***** extra ********
data _null_;
set &dataset ;
%do i=1 to &total;
   call symputx ( "var&i" !! left(_n_), &&variable&i );
%end;
run;
***** extra ********
*/

%mend definevar;

%definevar( ifanylibrary, parm2)
```

*And I am looking forward to learn CALL VNEXT solution by @Reeza*